# Loop through 2 rows, merge and remove duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, associative-array, duplicates

I have 2 rows in a mysql table. Some of the data is duplicated across the rows, and some is duplicated in the same row. I would like to echo out each unique value.

The array looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Character1] => Moe Szyslak [Character2] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [Character1] => Homer Simpson [Character2] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [Character1] => Homer  Simpson [Character2] => ) [3] => Array ( [Character1] => Homer Simpson [Character2] => Marge Simpson )
```

Have tried various things, `foreach's` combined with array_unique etc, but nothing is even close so I'm thinking I must be way off. The expected result is:
`Moe Szyslak Homer Simpson Marge Simpson`

EDIT: The query is in a CI Model (And yeah my db structure should be much better):

```
function getCharacter()
{
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT Character1, Character2 FROM clip");
return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: can you add the query you use in getting those records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DISTINCT Character1, Character2` will only weed out rows containing same `Character1` and `Character2`. So for the below data, three rows would be returned - row 2, row 4 and one of (row 1 and 3)

```
Character1    | Character2
-----------------------------
Moe Szyslak   | Homer Simpson 
Marge Simpson | Moe Szyslak 
Moe Szyslak   | Homer Simpson 
Moe Szyslak   | Marge Simpson
```

Use the below code to get the unique values

```
$charaters = array();
foreach ($charater_arr as $charater_arr) {
  if (!in_array($charater_arr['Character1'], $charaters)) {
    $charaters[]  = $charater_arr['Character1'];
  }
  if (!in_array($charater_arr['Character1'], $charaters)) {
    $charaters[]  = $charater_arr['Character2'];
  }
}
print_r($charaters);
```

Else try the below query.

```
SELECT Character1 AS character FROM clip 
UNION
SELECT Character2 AS character FROM clip
```

Comment: That nearly worked, it just literally removed all duplicates - so I'm left with no homers. (It only echo'd out the unique values in the table.)

Comment: @jaybong isn't that what you wanted ?

Comment: Ah sorry, I had an error in the code so it only returned results if they were unique in the table (if they were dupes it didn't return the first result). Now it works perfectly, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do a "select distinct *" from your table to remove dupes?

Another option would be to check the previous value in the array:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    if ($i == 0 || $array[$i]->Character1 != $array[$i - 1]->Character1)
    {
        echo $array[$i]->Character1 ."<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason the select distinct wouldn't work, that was the initial plan.

Comment: Re the code, it gives an error 'Trying to get property of non-object' in the if condition and on a later line if I edit the conditional statement. I guess it's because of the $array[$i]->Character1 syntax. I changed all instances in your code of $array to the actual name of the array ($characterArr) but still giving the error. I get the concept but I'm new to this so have so far failed to fix the syntax.